# GoogleScraper (Python Script) error: "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: aiohttp"

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

I am trying to get [GoogleScraper](https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper) Python script working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, but am getting the following error when I type "./GoogleScraper -h"

```
<code>
 ./GoogleScraper -h
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./GoogleScraper", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/home/roger/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2716, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/home/roger/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 685, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/home/roger/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: aiohttp
</code>
```

What do I do to install this aiohttp package?  [I googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound%3A%20aiohttp&oq=pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound%3A%20aiohttp&aqs=chrome..69i57.294j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=119&ie=UTF-8#q=pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound:%20aiohttp) and was a little confused.

Here is my "Python -V" output

`roger@vbox-ubuntu:~/env/bin$ python -V
Python 2.7.6
roger@vbox-ubuntu:~/env/bin$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.0`

I also ran the following prior:

`virtualenv --python python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install GoogleScraper
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install aiohttp`

Comment: Do you use python virtual environment tools like virtualenv, pyenv etc.?

Comment: I did, as per the tutorial on GitHub:  "virtualenv --python python3 env"

Comment: I'm wondering if it's related to the Chrome driver.  That's what I'm looking into now.  https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

Comment: FWIW, just asked the author of the program on GitHub.  https://github.com/NikolaiT/GoogleScraper/issues/106

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo pip3 install aiohttp
```

should fix your problem (preceded by `sudo apt-get install python3-pip` if pip is not installed yet)

Comment: I ran both of those commands (apt-get and then pip3), but I still get the same error.

Comment: Yup, same error.  "GoogleScraper -h" in the /bin folder gives "pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: aiohttp"

Comment: Did you use the --system-site-packages option of virtualenv?

Comment: No, I didn't.  I will look at that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like much of my problem was running "sudo apt-get install" in my local environment.

My fix was starting with a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 LTS install and then running the following:

`sudo apt-get install python-virtualenv python3-pip liblz-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev zlib1g-dev python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev ubuntu-desktop chromium-chromedriver google-chrome-stable`

After that, I ran the following commands on the author's website:

`virtualenv --python python3 env
source env/bin/activate
pip install GoogleScraper
sudo pip3 install aiohttp`

After that, I was able to get "GoogleScraper -h" to output the help file, as expected.